# How to apply a css rule based on the number of siblings an element has?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I have an element that may contain 1, 2 or 3 subelements:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element" />
</div>
```

or...

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element" />
  <div class="element" />
</div>
```

or...

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element" />
  <div class="element" />
  <div class="element" />
</div>
```

I want to apply styles to .element depending on how many siblings there are.

For example, something like...

```
.wrapper .element {
width: 50%;
}

.wrapper .element:only-child {
width: 75%;
}
```

...but I cannot figure out how to differentiate between the 2 elements and the 3 elements.  Is this possible in pure css?

Thanks ( in advance ) for your help.

Comment: There's no pure-CSS solution to this (so far as I'm aware), as yet. However it could be done with some HTML-changes, or with JavaScript.

Comment: Use `jQuery` if you don't want to add `data-` attribute if the number of sub-elements change frequently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy to do, usually people use the data attribute [thanks @david-thomas] in html to accomplish this:

A DIV wrapper and children:

```
<div class="wrapper" data-wrapper-subs="3">
    <div class="some-class">Child 1</div>
    <div class="some-class">Child 2</div>
    <div class="some-class">Child 3</div>
</div>
```

And its CSS:

```
div.wrapper[data-wrapper-subs="1"] div { width: 99%; }
div.wrapper[data-wrapper-subs="2"] div { width: 49%; }
div.wrapper[data-wrapper-subs="3"] div { width: 32%; }
div.wrapper[data-wrapper-subs="4"] div { width: 24%; }
div.wrapper[data-wrapper-subs="5"] div { width: 19%; }

div.wrapper div.some-class { /* Generic child styling */ }
```

The important thing is to set the `data-wrapper-subs` to the number of children.

If you don't know the number of children obviously this won't work, but as far as I know you can only style based on :first-child, :last-child, :only-child, :nth-child(odd), :nth-child(even) and :nth-child([number])

Comment: A touch of JS to dynamically add the data-element would solve the issue of not knowing how many children there are before hand

Comment: `data-*` is an *attribute* of an element, not an element itself. =)

Comment: @Dre you can do it using JS, yes, I tend to shy away from solutions that require JS for proper viewing though as people with it turned off may get an unusable view.

Comment: @david-thomas I agree; I would also ensure that there are relevant fallback styles in place to ensure that it was viewable (for example defaulting all widths to 100%). I must avoid leaving overly concise comments! In a real-world scenario I would shy away from this kind of layout; it